# Why my URL is not opening in the WebView component?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, webview

I have to put a chat URL to open in a webview, but it doesn't open. When I change the URL to the google URL, the webview works normally. Does anyone know why my URL is not opening but others, such as google's, open?

the URL I need to open is https://www10.directtalk.com.br/chat31/?idd=DDD70036929AA01535BF

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    chat_webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
    }

    chat_webview.apply {
        this.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        this.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
        this.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        this.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        this.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }




    firebaseChatURL().addOnSuccessListener {
        chat_webview.loadUrl(it["link"].toString())
    }
}

fun firebaseChatURL(): Task<DocumentSnapshot> =
firestore().document("Settings/chatURL").get()
```

Comment: Please post your code also

Comment: right, I posted it

Answer (score 0):

```
chat_webview.apply {
    this.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
    this.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
    this.settings.useWideViewPort = true
    this.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    this.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    this.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient() // add this line
}
```

please move the above code block first and then override the URL, you have not set up the webview and your are expecting the webview to override the URL that's why your URL is not loading.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggest, but I get the same result. The URL I'm getting from Firebase and the xml where the webview is, is instantiated in the onCreateView()

Comment: can you share the gist or code snippet of what you are actually doing? @atlas250